# Error argument length of 0, how to fix this

Tags: r

'I am trying to isolate water level data the corresponds with precipitation events and after the event is over'

```
well_data$Date <- as.POSIXct(well_data$Date, format("%Y/%m/%d"))
rainfall_event_data$Start <- as.POSIXct(rainfall_event_data$eventStart, format("%Y/%m/%d"))
rainfall_event_data$End <- as.POSIXct(rainfall_event_data$eventEnd, format("%Y/%m/%d"))

rainfall_event_data$Start <- rainfall_event_data$Start - 7*60


event_check_range <- 2*24 #2008 and 2009 data is hourly
na_counter <- 0

well_timestamp <- "Date"
well_data_name <- "DWL2015"
rainfall_timestamp <- "eventStart"
```

```
## 'Declaration of output Data frame'
    extraced_data <- data.frame("rise_start_timestamp", "rise_start_value", "peak_timestamp",    "Peak_value", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    complete_extracted_data <- data.frame()
'for(wells in 1:ncol(well_data))'
    for(rainfall_index in 1:nrow(rainfall_event_data)){
'Find the index in the well data for which the rainfall event corresponds'
    rainfall_event_start <- rainfall_event_data[rainfall_index, rainfall_timestamp]
    start_index <- which (well_data[[well_timestamp]] == rainfall_event_start)
    end_index <- start_index + event_check_range

    for (well_data_index in start_index:end_index){
    previous_well_data <- well_data[well_data_index - 1, well_data_name]
    current_well_data <- well_data[well_data_index, well_data_name]
    next_well_data <- well_data[well_data_index + 1, well_data_name]

# 'Error in start_index:end_index : argument of length 0'
```

Comment: Hi Kimberly, welcome to the site! I've added more code formatting to your question, but as you can see there are a bunch of extra \ escape characters - maybe you pasted your code into some intermediary before into your question? Anyway, it makes your code difficult to read and impossible to run. Perhaps you can edit it to make it more accessible?

Comment: On the "impossible to run" end, it would help a lot if you could provide enough sample data for us to try to run your code. If you could share a few rows of data with `dput()` that would be a big help. (You can use, e.g., `dput(rainfall_event_data[1:5, ])` to make copy/pasteable R code to recreate the first 5 rows of `rainfall_event_data`.)

Comment: Without that, I can only guess at the issue, but I see that you define `start_index` as `which (well_data[[well_timestamp]] == rainfall_event_start)`. My guess is that there are some cases where there is not `well_timestamp` that is equal to a `rainfall_event_start`, so `which()` returns nothing, which has length 0, and then `start_index:end_index` throws your error.  Without seeing your data or understanding your goal, it's hard to know how to fix this.

Comment: Lastly, a minor comment, when you do your date conversions you use `as.POSIXct(well_data$Date, format("%Y/%m/%d"))`, but I think you probably want `as.POSIXct(well_data$Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d")`. What you have works due to luck - `as.POSIXct` expects the 2nd argument to be named `format` and the `format()` function has no effect on `"%Y/%m/%d"`, but using the `format()` function here is not needed and could cause bugs with other inputs.